# Android studio: can we directly edit string.xml from java source file?

Tags: android, android-studio

While editing code sometimes we might need to change the string value in strings.xml, what is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: ctrl+click and then shift+f6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For windows/Linux:**

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover your mouse over the reference of ***string***. It will create a link that will take your cursor to the string.xml file
.

**For Mac:**

Hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> button and do the same thing as above.

Example: [image]

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can do **Alt + Enter** in your string and Android Studio will show you this:

[image]

From there you can Extract string resources